# How to keep a code line running and work in other lines in single google colab notebook or use 2 notebooks over same data?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I want to run a python script over the colab notebook that scrapes the data and save it in a database inside the colab files. This script needs to be kept runnning. Additionally, I have another script that will plot graphs from the data being stored in the database, and I do not want to disturb the scraping operation. Is it possible to perform such operation?

I saw the multiprocessing method but I find it to be working with single programs and functions, and not with multilines.

I expect the result to be either in a single colab notebook or in two colab notebooks sharing same set of files or atleast same database getting modified in real-time. Also, I do not want to store the database locally.